# Excel sheet not saved but reading values

Tags: php, excel

I have one Excel sheet which is getting updated every seconds by some other application or feed but that application is just updating the values in it, it's not storing or saving it. I'm using this code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('asia/kolkata');
require_once 'excel_reader/Excel/reader.php';
echo $scrptstrt = 'Start = ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s:u') . '====' . microtime();
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'stock');
}
$file_name = 'Arbitrage.xls';
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
$data->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
$data->read('C:/ODIN/DIET/' . $file_name);
```

But this code is reading the values properly if and only if Excel sheet is saved.

Comment: `Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader !== PHPExcel`

Comment: That's logical.... Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader can only read a file, not the current of another application, so if the other application doesn't save to file then SER can't read from it

Comment: But the other application must save to file at some point, perhaps change that so that it saves more frequently

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks for response. and thanks a lot to understand my problem accurately. is there any way so that we can fetch the data from excelsheet in such situation?

Comment: That requires the other application to explicitly provide a sharing mechanism; and for your script to be able to access that sharing mechanism.... which SER won't do.... Normally programs are written so that they cannot access each others memory space, to provide referential integrity within the program. It's possible, but would certainly require significant changes to code on both sides